# How to access network location using phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am new to `phonegap`. How can I access location that is provided by the service provider in phone (without using the GPS),the default location shows in phone. I need to collect to the location and store it when needed.

If possible this , Its helps me when shows the complete code for as demo.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you must have internet connection to use geolocation functionality.

Sample access location.

Install geolocation cordova plugin.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Replace index.html with this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Build your project.

```
cordova build ios
cordova build android
```

Run your project

Comment: Okey. Is that so how can it be possible? . Can you show one example to access the location.

Comment: Super ..it worked fine.. is it working with any use of GPS? i dnt hav any idea about it dats y.

Comment: Is there any method to collect current data to server a when it needed through internet.?(like triggering an event or calling a function to collect the current data from the device to server using server side scripting through internet. )

Comment: Sure you can. just using ajax can collect current data to server.

Comment: Can you explain it  or share any document regarding it?

Comment: try look at this, http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/15/simple-hybrid-mobile-app-using-cordova-and-ratchet-2-complete/

Comment: Wow..its a great one. lemme study about it.. Please don’t hesitate to help me If need more clarification

Comment: No problem my friend.

Comment: I have added code to access geolocation in mob. Is it possible to take current data from mobile to my server when needed? (without opening the app. like when I trigger a function or something like that in my server side and it collect the current location from the mobile).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72193/discussion-between-v-p-and-dato-mohammad-nurdin).